# Which is the best option to compress a 3 minute audio file for an iphone app?

Tags: ios

I have 30 audios that need to be in the app. Each audio is around 3 minutes long. The original file size of a single audio file is around 5mb and I need to compress it so the app wont be bulky. Is there any option to compress the audio file without losing the quality??
This is for an ios app

Comment: every lossy compression affect quality of media. You can't avoid it. With audio compression involve sampling. You should tell more about what file you tried to compress - mp3?

Comment: I had a similar problem with just 7 files! For me, making the files mono worked. It meant they could remain as CAF...

Comment: the original files are in .wav format

Answer (score 3):

From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW28):

> ## Preferred Audio Formats in iOS
>
> For uncompressed (highest quality) audio, use 16-bit, little endian, linear PCM audio data packaged in a CAF file.
>
> For compressed audio when playing one sound at a time, and when you don’t need to play audio simultaneously with the iPod application, use the AAC format packaged in a CAF or m4a file.
>
> ## Hardware assisted decoding
>
> - AAC (MPEG-4 Advanced Audio Coding)
> - ALAC (Apple Lossless)
> - HE-AAC (MPEG-4 High Efficiency AAC)
> - MP3 (MPEG-1 audio layer 3)

Try different formats and see what is best for your project. Compressed audio is not synonym for bad quality.